# No output for seaborn distplot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

I was trying to plot a seaborn distplot.

sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data
np.random.seed(365)
x1 = np.random.normal(10, 3.4, size=1000)  # mean of 10
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': x1})

def map_pdf(x, **kwargs):
    mu, std = scipy.stats.norm.fit(x)
    x0, x1 = p1.axes[0][0].get_xlim()  # axes for p1 is required to determine x_pdf
    x_pdf = np.linspace(x0, x1, 100)
    y_pdf = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x_pdf, mu, std)
    plt.plot(x_pdf, y_pdf, c='r')


p1 = sns.displot(data=df, x='x1', kind='hist', bins=40, stat='density')
p1.map(map_pdf, 'x1')
```

not sure why I am not getting any output after executing the above code!

Upon execution above code, i am getting this,

```
<seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid at 0x7f6a6fa0f820>
```

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for the support!

Comment: This code works fine with `seaborn 0.11.2` and `matplotlib 3.4.3`. See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRKGu.png)

Comment: If you are using Jupyter Notebook, add `%matplotlib inline` to your imports & try again

Comment: Yay, I get to point someone to the new [FAQ page](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions-(FAQs)#why-arent-my-plots-showing-up) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `plt.show` to display your plot. The same was recreated and furnished below with the solution.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data
np.random.seed(365)
x1 = np.random.normal(10, 3.4, size=1000)  # mean of 10
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': x1})

def map_pdf(x, **kwargs):
    mu, std = scipy.stats.norm.fit(x)
    x0, x1 = p1.axes[0][0].get_xlim()  # axes for p1 is required to determine x_pdf
    x_pdf = np.linspace(x0, x1, 100)
    y_pdf = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x_pdf, mu, std)
    plt.plot(x_pdf, y_pdf, c='r')


p1 = sns.displot(data=df, x='x1', kind='hist', bins=40, stat='density')
p1.map(map_pdf, 'x1')
plt.show(p1)
```

Comment: @adey27, were you able to resolve your issue with the above solution?

Comment: thanks.. It did work after adding '%matplotlib inline'